# Getting error cannot find name 'book' Angular 7

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, angular7

Trying to fix old code and I'm getting error can't fine name 'book'. I'm pretty new to this, so any help is appreciated. Should there be a class book involved somehow? ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(31,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'book'.

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
      <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let book of books | async">
              <pre>{{ book | json }}</pre>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <button (click)="addBook()">Add a book!</button>
      <button (click)="filterBooks()">Filter books</button>
  `
})


export class AppComponent {

  public books: AngularFireList<any[]>;

  private bookCounter = 0;

  private filter = '';

  constructor(public title, private af: AngularFireDatabase) {
      this.books = af.list('/books');
  }

  public addBook(): void {
      const newBook = new book(`My book #${this.bookCounter++}`);
      this.books.push(newBook);
  }

  public filterBooks(): void {
      this.books = this.af.list('/books', ref =>
      ref.orderByChild('title').equalTo('My book #1'));

  }
}
```

Comment: are you imported `book` class ?  If not just import the class

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to instantiate a book class:

```
const newBook = new book(`My book #${this.bookCounter++}`);
```

But you haven't imported the book class, so just import it and it should fix your error.